# 2021 Angular and AngularDart , what are features missing?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

After I studied *flutter* and *dart* .. and as i know **Angular/typescript**.

I wonder !!

what are features available in Angular which are missing from **AngularDart** 2021 .. is **AngularDart** complete? why not popular?

Comment: You should not use AngularDart for new project: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/announce/c/Kz84KNBcf3U?pli=1

Comment: Downvote will be changed to upvote with time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like google does not focus much on angularDart in the future. afaik